# Acces button from container of buttons JAVA

Tags: java, containers, jbutton

I want to make an interface for a Minesweeper game in java and i have this for now:

```
Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));

   for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) 
   {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        pane.add(button);

   }
```

I don't want the JButtons to have any text at start, but when i click on a certain button i need to get that buttons row and column in the gridview, i will call a function that will give me a number of bombs near that point and i will put that number as the text from that button that was clicked, any help? i don't know how to get a specific button from a gridview so i can change it's propreties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to create an `ActionListener` class of your own that gets a row and column passed into it when these buttons are created.  When their action is fired, they can just pass that in to the function you're referring to.  Something like this:

```
package com.sandbox;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container pane = //...
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
                JButton button = new JButton();
                button.addActionListener(new PositionAwareActionListener(r, c));
                pane.add(button);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class PositionAwareActionListener implements ActionListener {
        private int r;
        private int c;

        public PositionAwareActionListener(int r, int c) {
            this.r = r;
            this.c = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //callYourFunction(r, c);
        }
    }


}
```